# Function to refactor AJAX post: Get field ID that changed and post it's value with AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm a new developer asking my first SO question :). Working on a form that has some calculated fields based off corresponding text inputs in ASP.NET MVC. Essentially, takes value from text box, AJAX post that value to controller, perform calc, returns that data to read-only calculated field.

I have the following code for this working:

```
$("#volume").focusout(function () {
           volume = $(this).val()

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '/StaffingPlan/CalculatorAction',
               data: { volume: volume },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   $("#selectorsNeeded").val(data);
               }
           });
       });

$("#drops").focusout(function () {
           drops = $(this).val()

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '/StaffingPlan/CalculatorAction',
               data: { drops: drops },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   $("#liftsNeeded").val(data);
               }
           });
       });
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult CalculatorAction(string volume, string drops)
        {

            int data = 0;

            //one calculation performed for volume, but will be others to calculate
            if (volume != null && volume != "")
            {
               data = Int32.Parse(volume) / 150 / 9;
            }

            //example of another calc
            if (drops != null && drops != "")
            {
                data = Int32.Parse(drops) / 25 / 6;
            }
            
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This works, however, the form has several other inputs and calculated fields. Obviously there's better/dryer way to write this instead of duplicating the .focusout function. Would be nice to just get the field ID that changes and assign value to appropriate variable. Hope this makes sense! Any direction would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$("#volume").focusout(function () {
 
 var data= { volume: $(this).val()},
 var resultField=  $("#selectorsNeeded");
  calculateResult(data, resultField);
     });    

$("#drops").focusout(function () {
   
          var data= { drops: $(this).val() },
           var resultField=  $("#liftsNeeded");
        calculateResult(data, resultField);
     });   

function calculateResult (data, resultField) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '/StaffingPlan/CalculatorAction',
               data: data,
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (result) {
                   console.log(result);
                 resultField.val(result);
               }
           });
       };
```